# Monitor Flickers after resolution detection

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution, lg

### Problem

Everything used to be fine until I broke my monitor 
(LG W2284F : `1680x1050`) and I bought a new monitor (LG 25UM65-P: `2560x1080`).

The Problem is when I try to install Ubuntu or any other linux-dist OS, after resolution detection Monitor Flickers.

### Facts

Graphic Card is NVIDIA GForce 9500 GT. (used to support my previous monitor resolution with Ubuntu)

Monitor flickers not the screen , as long monitor buttons does not work.
I tried monitor with both DVI-D and HDMI cable.

### What Have I Done?

Based on some topics and issues I tried booting with `nomodeset` and it works and let me install Ubuntu. Now, the only available resolution is `800x600` after and while installation.

`xrandr` does not work returning

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed.
```

and also nvidia graphic drive installation asks for kernel v3.4.

Is there any solution to use my monitor default resolution?

---

```
$ lshw -c display
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G96 [GeForce 9500 GT]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fa000000-fbffffff ioport:cc00(size=128) memory:fe980000-fe9fffff

$ xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 (0x17d) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
Identifier: 0x17c
Timestamp:  28516
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:    
CRTC:       0
CRTCs:      0
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
  640x480 (0x17d)   22.4MHz *current
        h: width   640 start    0 end    0 total  640 skew    0 clock   35.0KHz
        v: height  480 start    0 end    0 total  480           clock   73.0Hz
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you [edit] the question and add output of `sudo lshw -c display; xrandr --verbose` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I just solved the problem.

- The Problem was the DVI-D cable type. so tricky there are two type of DVI Digital: Single link and Dual Link ... Just Bought a new DVI-D Dual Link and Problem was ... half resolved.
- The other problem is that DVI-D Does not support Wide Resolution and based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413627/unable-to-get-2560x1440-to-output-through-dvi) question and  [Linus Post](https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/HQsCY7ErAL4) It was all resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You display adapter (nvidia) seems not receiving the DDC/CI data from the new screen.

As:

- I can see from it [LG 25UM65-P Specification Sheet](http://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-25UM65-P#tech-specs) it should support that. (Anyway any modern monitor should have this)
- You have tried two digital cables DVI-D and HDMI without success.

So for solution:

- It could be that DDC/CI sending feature is disabled in the monitor (I have one Dell monitor that offer possibility to disable it)

  Look for DDC/CI or EDID and enable it. (I looked at manual but does not seem there)
- If you are using an adapter, look for a direct & relatively short cable.
- A workaround when no EDID data available from monitor

  Create a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file that contains

  ```
  Section "Monitor"
      Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
      HorizSync       30.0 - 90.0
      VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
  EndSection
  ```

  Values got from the user manual.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the xorg.conf file description you used but instead of Horiz and Vert I used Modeline.